# How do I apply a fill to this Path?

Tags: react-native, svg

I'm trying to fill the path of this Path in an SVG which is a hexagon.

```
<Path d="M205 3521 l-200 -117 -2 -240 -3 -239 204 -117 204 -116 204 118 203 118 0 243 0 243 -195 113 c-107 62 -199 112 -205 112 -5 0 -100 -53 -210 -118z m395 -38 l170 -98 -3 -214 -2 -214 -178 -104 -179 -104 -179 103 -179 102 0 211 1 210 177 102 c97 56 183 103 189 103 7 0 89 -44 183 -97z" fill="red" />
```

I'm using React Native but the syntax is the same. Filling the path red applies to the outside border.

Comment: Because the path consists of two hexagons, one inside the other so the inside of the path is the area between the hexagons. Sounds like you need to draw a different hexagonal path. If you're not sure how to draw a path, using an SVG drawing program and viewing what it creates is probably the easiest way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a path with a fill. However it's a path with a hole.

One solution to your problem would be deleting everything in your path's `d` attribute from `m395 -38` to the end. (This is the hole part)

```css
svg{border:1px solid;width:85vh;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox ="0 2690 820 950">
<path id = "kk" 
      d="M205 3521 
         l-200 -117 
         -2 -240 
         -3 -239 
         204 -117 
         204 -116 
         204 118 
         203 118 
         0 243 
         0 243 
         -195 113 
         c-107 62 -199 112 -205 112 
         -5 0 -100 -53 -210 -118z 
         " fill="red" />
</svg>
```

However if you need to keep the actual shape and fill it with a different color, in this case you may copy everything in your path's `d` from the beginning to the first z and create an other path using the copied part as the `d` attribute. Put this new path before the old one.

```css
svg{border:1px solid;width:85vh}
```

```html
<svg viewBox ="0 2690 820 950">
  
<path d="M205 3521 
         l-200 -117 
         -2 -240 
         -3 -239 
         204 -117 
         204 -116 
         204 118 
         203 118 
         0 243 
         0 243 
         -195 113 
         c-107 62 -199 112 -205 112 
         -5 0 -100 -53 -210 -118z" fill="skyBlue"/>
<path 
      d="M205 3521 
         l-200 -117 
         -2 -240 
         -3 -239 
         204 -117 
         204 -116 
         204 118 
         203 118 
         0 243 
         0 243 
         -195 113 
         c-107 62 -199 112 -205 112 
         -5 0 -100 -53 -210 -118z 
         m395 -38 
         l170 -98
         -3 -214 
         -2 -214 
         -178 -104 
         -179 -104 
         -179 103 
         -179 102 
         0 211 
         1 210 
         177 102 
         c97 56 183 103 189 103
         7 0 89 -44 183 -97z" fill="red" />
  
  
  
</svg>
```